# Terminal font is not smooth

Tags: terminal, font

I am new to Mac, and I am finding that the fonts are not smooth.

Changing the system defaults (`defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 2`, "Use LCD font smoothing" checked) do not improve the fonts.

Here is a comparison of rendering in Terminal (above) and EMACS (below), both with Monaco-16.

[image: Mac Terminal and Emacs fonts]

- How can I fix this?
- Are there other, prettier terminal emulators?

System: MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up the Preferences in Terminal and check "Antialias Text" under the Text tab of the Settings page. This is the page that shows different "Profiles" for your Terminal appearance as well.

Comment: that did it. Thanks. Seems odd that it is disabled by default.

Comment: Thank you so much @krs013, I tried a number of solutions including the one mentioned in the question, and it finally works!